# UITableViewDelegate didSelectRowAt Conditionally Execute based on Row

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch, didselectrowatindexpath

I am interested in being able to conditionally execute code based on what row a user selects. Is there a way to associate an identifier with each row (cell) in cellForRowAt to help distinguish which row is selected to be used in DidSelectRowAt delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are correct in using the `DidSelectRowAt` method. If you have a  view controller with the table, the view controller will have to adopt the two standard delegates: `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    let message:[String] = ["Hello", "World", "How", "Are", "You"]

    /* Table with five rows */
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    /*Have a simple table with cells being the words in the message */
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = message[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    /*Optional method to determine which row was pressed*/
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        print("I'm row number "+String(indexPath.row))
    }

    /*set the table's delegate and datasource to the view controller*/
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.table.delegate = self
        self.table.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

[image: App Image]

This would output:
`I'm row number 1`
*Recall that indexes start at zero*.

Comment: I have this built out already - sorry for not posting what I currently have (its rather extensive). I'm wondering if there's a way to associate what is displayed on cellForRowAt, and then be able to be referenced in didSelectRowAt. For example, if I were to click on the row and it says "Hello", execute one thing, and if the row says "World", execute another.

Comment: @Kevin A way to go about it is to simply use a switch statement to handle what `indexPath.row`is in the `DidSelectRowAt` method, and call the appropriate function that corresponds to that row.

Comment: what values are held in indexPath.row? From my understanding, I thought it only was the row number selected. Is there more information that is associated with indexPath.row?

Comment: Yes, by using the row number to look up the appropriate entry in your data source.